# How to arrange items inside of LinearLayout to match to the parent width on android

Tags: android

I have some items inside of my `LinearLayout` and what I want to do is, arrange the items vertically in a way that it would spread evenly with default margin across the items.

This is what I have now :

[image]

So All the FAB's inside of the linear layout doesn't spread evenly, and even if I set a `layout_marginStart` it could cause some problems due to different resolutions across the android models.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right">
            <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/gray"
                app:elevation="0dp"
                android:src="@android:color/transparent" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:text="S"
                android:elevation="16dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
        </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe you could try some mathematics with width of the screen and arrange them accordingly!

Comment: The best approach for this would be using ConstraintLayout with Horizontal Chain.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead of FrameLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp">
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:src="@android:color/transparent"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/gray"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:elevation="0dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:elevation="16dp"
        android:text="S"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="10sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The children of a LinearLayout spread evenly when they have android:layout_width="0dp" and android:layout_weight="1"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `layout_weight="value"` property. So you can set the weight for each FAB so that they can evenly get separated in the layout.

For example if you want three FABs evenly seperate, you can set `layout_weight="1"` for each FAB, then it will seperate evenly. You can also use Decimal Values instead of 1.